# How to return appreciation in Italian?

Tags: phrase-request

In English, "thank *you*" (with the stress on the *you*) is often used in response to someone who has just said "thank you", to reciprocate gratitude. For example, someone providing a service usually says "thank you" to the customer benefiting from the service. An appreciative customer would say "thank *you*" to humbly suggest they should be the one "giving thanks" (for the service).

> Example - A waiter or maître d' of a restaurant is saying goodbye to a customer
>
> **Waiter**: Thank you! (for dining with us)
>
> **Diner**: No, thank *you*!

I'm wondering what, if any, the Italian equivalent to this would be? Would it be *a te*? Would something like the following ever be used?

> **Waiter**: Arrivederci, grazie!
>
> **Diner**: (No,) a te!

Comment: Welcome on ItalianSE!!!

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent answer could be:

> **Waiter**: Arrivederci, grazie! 
> **Diner**: No, ***grazie a te***!

You could also answer ***grazie a voi*** in order to include all the personnel involved in the service or ***grazie a Lei*** since in Italian there are two address forms and “Lei” is the formal one.

In general you can also omit No just saying ***Grazie a te/Lei/voi*** or even just ***A te/Lei/voi***. (Thanks @Charo and @DaG)

Comment: That's OK, but I think you can also answer "A te!" (or "A voi!" or "A lei!") with "grazie" omitted.

Comment: I wouldn't say at all “No”, but just “(Grazie) a te/lei/voi!”.